# How to search/find a method or attribute on a Python object? (search all descendents)

Tags: python

I am working with a 3rd party library that I am new to.  There's a method that I'm trying to call, but I can't find it.  It's in `self` ... somewhere.  It could be on a child attribute or on a child of a child, or on a child of a child of a child -- deep down in `self`.  But I can't find it.  It's a large tree, so finding this is taking a long time.

How do I find it?

This is a generic problem.  It can happen to anyone when learning a new library, especially a complex one, for the first time.  We all know to RTFM, but sometimes that isn't enough.  If we have access to the source, we can read the source.  But, if the library is complex, heavily decorated, wrapped, re-factored, SOLID principle'd library, the above might not be very fruitful.

I've tried to mess with `vars()`, `dir()` and the `inspect` module, but so far no good.  I'm probably using them wrong.

Comment: Is the library and its source publicly available?

Comment: Yes, but this is a generic problem that I run into a lot when trying to learn a new lib.

Comment: There is a library for [high school students](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/lumpy.html). It may work with your objects ;)

Comment: The generic answer to that problem is reading documentation and if necessary, source. Introspecting at runtime is not a sensible way to find an API.

Comment: Besides documentation, searchable faqs and howtos could be part of the generic answer.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is that the instantiated object could have accumulated new properties at run time that the documentation might have missed (and often does miss or lightly cover)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some hackish code which recursively crawls through the attributes of an object, looking for any attribute with a given name.
In the example, the `numpy` package is searched for any attribute with the name `normal`.

**Edit**: The code now also search in superclasses.

```
import numpy

# Hackish function doing the recursive attribute search
def find_attr(object_name, attr_name):
    matches = []
    def f(a, search, names=None, objects=None):
        if not hasattr(a, '__dict__'):
            return
        if names is None:
            names = []
            objects = []
        for varname, var in vars(a).items():
            if varname in names:
                if var in objects:
                    continue
            if varname == search:
                matches.append(object_name + '.' + varname1 + '.' + '.'.join(names + [varname]))
            result = f(var, search, names + [varname], objects + [var])
    mother_obj = eval(object_name)
    for varname1 in dir(mother_obj):
        if varname1 == attr_name:
            matches.append(object_name + '.' + varname1)
        try:
            var = getattr(mother_obj, varname1)
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        f(var, attr_name)
    return sorted(matches, key=len) 

# Define your search
object_name = 'numpy'
attr_name = 'normal'

# Do the search
matches = find_attr(object_name, attr_name)
print('\n'.join(matches))
```

This gives me 1240 results, the first one being `numpy.random.normal`.

Note that the search can take some time to complete when searching through a deep object like this. The above example takes 2 minutes on my computer.

Comment: This is a start.  How about from an already instantiated object?

Comment: This should work for an already instantiated object. Just write the name of the object as a string in `object_name`.

Comment: I have updated the code. It now find more results than before, as superclasses of instances are also searched.

Comment: When I use this on an instantiated object, it says NameError: name 'whatever' is not defined.